# JComboBox Item Listener - Does not work in if statement

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Good day to all,

I have a JComboBox which contains the following items:

```
"SELECT WHICH ROW / COLUMN / SAMPLE"
"ROW"
"COLUMN"
"SAMPLE"
```

If the user selected ROW or COLUMN, it would display another JComboBox which would allow users to select the specific Row or Column it wants to display. On the other hand, if the user has selected SAMPLE, it would display a JTextField which has its own purpose on other parts of my code.

My question is, why is it when I check in my actionPerformed function whether the item ["SAMPLE"] has been selected in my JComboBox, it does enter that certain if statement?

```
if(selection1agraph.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("SAMPLE"))
```

Here is the segment of my code:

  - selection1a is a JComboBox that has the same functionality with selection1agraph, but differs with its contents
  - selection1agraph is the JComboBox where the problem occurs
  - selection2a is the JComboBox which would be displayed when the user selects either Row or Column
  - selection4 is the JTextField which would be displayed when the user selects Sample
  - values is a HashSet which allows me to compare multiple variation of Strings

I have used the same else if statement for selection1a and selection1agraph because they have the same functionality execpt that selection1a only contains the following items:

*"SELECT WHICH ROW / COLUMN"*
*"ROW"*
*"COLUMN"*

```
else if (ie.getSource() == selection1a || ie.getSource() == selection1agraph) {
    if (ie.getItem().toString().trim().equals("ROW")) {
       .... //other code here
    }

    else if (ie.getItem().toString().trim().equals("COLUMN")) {

        .... //other if and else if statements here

        else if (ie.getSource() == selection1a || ie.getSource() == selection1agraph){
             selection2a.setEnabled(true);
             if(ie.getSource() == selection1agraph){
                     if(values.contains(selection0.getSelectedItem().toString().trim())){
                       System.out.println("Entered values.contains(selection0)");
                          if(selection1agraph.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals("SAMPLE")){
                               System.out.println("Entered selection1agraph.getselectedItem()");
                                   selection2a.setEnabled(false);
                                   selection4.setEnabled(true);
                                   selection4.setVisible(true);
                           }
                     }
              }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you to those who will be able to help.

Comment: Is it really SAMPLE or Sample like you mentioned "whether the item ["Sample"] "?

Comment: It's SAMPLE. Sorry, let me edit that.

Comment: For better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. You might very well solve the problem yourself by simply trying to isolate and expose the bug.